# Map method expects a callback from arrow function (Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function)?

Tags: reactjs, html-lists

```
 import React from 'react';
 const UsersList = (props) => {
     return(
         <ul>
             {props.Users.map((user)=> {
                 <li>
                     {user.age} {user.age}
                 </li>
             })}
         </ul>
     );
 }
 export default UsersList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, you are not returning anything. Either use:

```
{props.Users.map((user)=> {
              return (
                 <li>
                     {user.age} {user.age}
                 </li>
              )
             })}
```

or use the implicit return:

```
{props.Users.map((user)=> (
                 <li>
                     {user.age} {user.age}
                 </li>
             ))}
```

Comment: The error was went but i did not seen anything rendering this list of user on web page

Comment: try `console.log(props.Users)` and see if you have the array. Otherwise, there is no reason it shouldn't render.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, map requires a return value and it will create a new array of all the returned values.
This code won't run as the return value is an array not JSX, what I would do is then call the reduce method and return a string with all the values:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce